# Log4net Add Header and footer for every exception logged

Tags: c#, log4net, rollingfileappender

I am using Log4net for logging for our application. I have a requirement to add header and footer for every exception logged in a file. Currently i have added Header and footer tag in layout but its not working. Following are my configurations in web.config file

```
    <log4net debug="true">
    <!-- Appenders for Log4Net library -->
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="${TMP}\Logging\log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />     
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="2MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <header value="[Header]&#13;&#10;" />
          <footer value="[Footer]&#13;&#10;" />
        <conversionPattern value="%date{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <levelMin value="ERROR" />
            <levelMax value="FATAL" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <header value="[Header]&#13;&#10;" />
          <footer value="[Footer]&#13;&#10;" />
        <conversionPattern value="%date{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <!--<root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />      
    </root>-->

    <logger name="EventLogger">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
    </logger>

     <logger name="FileLogger">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </logger>

  </log4net>
```

Regards

Comment: Headers and footers are once per log session, not once per log event. You may have to write a custom logger that adds them manually when it receives an exception object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the header and footer be part of the message, and in each message. Add it to the message it self. When you define a different header and footer, it is only logged at the start and end of a logging session.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Peter